# System of differential equations where generalized eigenvectors are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I am stuck on the following problem:$$\vec{X}'(t)=\begin{pmatrix}x'(t)\\y'(t)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -1 &1\\0 &-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x(t)\\y(t)\end{pmatrix}\ \ \ \ \vec{X}(0)=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$
I know that since the eigenvalues are repeted, we have to use generalized eigenvectors. But, in this case , the generalized eigenvectors seem to be the same. How do we find $x(t),y(t)$ in this case? Any hints. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: To find the generalized eigenvector, we can try $[A - \lambda I]v_2 = v_1$, which gives us $v_2 = (0,1)$ with $v_1 = (1,0)$. Then see, for example, https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-iv-first-order-systems/matrix-methods-eigenvalues-and-normal-modes/MIT18_03SCF11_s33_8text.pdf

Comment: @Moo oh yes, thanks, just missed it!